# "I would do anything you asked me to"

Tags: difference, tense, past-vs-past-perfect

What exactly does it mean? 
What is the difference between:

> I would do anything you asked me to!
>   I would have done anything you **had asked** me to!

Comment: What do you think is the difference?

Comment: Strictly speaking *I would have done anything you HAD ASKED me to* is syntactically "consistent", but most native speakers wouldn't bother repeating the Perfect form. Having said that, it *could* perhaps be included to resolve potential ambiguity, since *...anything you **asked*** could be used in contexts where ***I would*** refers to (a) a *[habitual] **past*** situation, OR (b) a hypothetical ***present / future*** situation. But that same distinction could also be made by going with *...anything you **ask*** for the hypothetical scenario.

Comment: Does this have a source? It's not exactly well-phrased...

Comment: Which part? Jan doggen

Answer (score -1):

Consider the difference:

> I will do anything you ask me to do.
>
> I would do anything you asked me to do.
>
> I would have done anything you had asked me to do.

The backshift to past-tense with **asked** and to past-perfect with **had asked** occurs to reflect the hypothetical conditionality of the statements in the respective main clause.